# Jython with java sandboxing: granting permissions more specific?

Tags: security, jython, sandbox, policy

I write a python- sandbox for running python scripts restricted, using Jython and the java security policy. To granting permissions I defined a policy file like this:

```
grant {

    permission java.io.FilePermission "Lib\\-", "read";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createClassLoader";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getProtectionDomain";

};
```

The FilePermission to read from the "Lib" folder of the jython.jar is required to import the os.py module in any python script, for example.

So jython has the grant to use e.g. `os.mkdir("Dir")` or `os.getpid()`, because the "os.py" module is in the jython.jar Lib folder.

How can I granting permissions more specific, e.g. the python script has permission to run `os.getpid()` but not `os.mkdir("Dir")` ?